# Conditional independence of two random variables given a third random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have three random variables $(X, Y, Z)$. The variables $X$ and $Y$ are *conditionally independent* given $Z$.

Will it be correct if I assume $P(X | Z) = P(X)$ or $P(X | Y) = P(X)$ ? If not, then why? Can you give a simple example to explain why the above assumption will not be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X:=\epsilon_1+Z$ and $Y:=\epsilon_2+Z$, where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are independent $N(0,1)$ (independent of $Z$) and $\mathsf{P}(Z=1)=\mathsf{P}(Z=-1)=1/2$.
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\le 0\mid Z)=\mathsf{P}(\epsilon_1+Z\le 0\mid Z)=\Phi(-Z).
$$
But $\mathsf{P}(X\le 0)=1/2$.

---

Conditional independence means that for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\in A, Y\in B\mid Z)=\mathsf{P}(X\in A\mid Z)\mathsf{P}(Y\in B\mid Z).
$$

Comment: Is $\Phi(Z)$ a cumulative probability function? And, is $Z$ symmetric about 0 ?

Comment: Yes, $\Phi$ is the cdf of $N(0,1)$.